# How can I read data from file and tokenize?

Tags: c, token

I have a 1024-bit `RSA` private key in text format in a file `privateKey.txt` contains,

```
RSA Private-Key: (1024 bit, 2 primes)
modulus:
    00:a3:38:61:b8:4a:29:60:2c:2f:6c:df:3b:e1:9b:
    b9:13:96:8f:dc:7f:b4:5a:7c:6d:61:6e:f4:df:63:
    36:1b:7c:97:b9:f5:03:8e:40:7e:ca:48:00:5f:b6:
    a3:51:66:39:7b:d2:b6:f0:5e:5e:93:de:e0:ec:c6:
    ae:bb:c5:3d:50:be:ca:e1:02:d0:0b:e2:36:75:43:
    e0:64:81:25:92:a6:26:e3:55:d8:cf:fe:f5:44:4f:
    c5:d5:1d:8a:6e:d2:3e:61:50:72:95:26:a2:7f:8a:
    66:a6:57:da:58:13:c7:9a:d4:b7:cb:5d:c7:c7:5e:
    d4:94:e5:b8:cc:e2:c4:2c:c3
publicExponent: 65537 (0x10001)
privateExponent:
    21:19:4b:e7:bd:52:4a:a8:6b:2d:9e:cf:5b:de:e2:
    57:30:8f:17:dd:e5:ca:fb:b4:8a:af:9f:84:b5:6f:
    c1:7f:30:9d:8b:2c:1f:6a:c0:cb:70:72:72:f6:6c:
    84:13:40:d0:f5:58:17:c2:6b:57:7d:39:0b:8a:f6:
    e0:29:0d:57:c1:73:99:1a:e1:e7:bc:52:15:89:08:
    7e:d5:cb:dc:be:0b:af:32:4c:b1:f3:cc:ea:bc:95:
    1a:37:19:5c:de:94:be:ca:9b:57:fb:42:01:1c:42:
    db:d5:b2:d4:16:f7:f2:dd:7f:28:c4:bb:67:9d:21:
    ef:4b:d2:b8:78:cf:f6:61
prime1:
    00:d7:84:e9:f3:4a:2b:f9:c2:de:a4:ce:6c:5d:57:
    fa:bd:77:c3:83:55:cf:b0:42:c8:9d:e4:85:60:dd:
    c8:9a:e4:f8:52:80:ac:fa:cb:33:36:2f:cf:ad:8d:
    2a:7b:9e:6a:dc:6f:94:d9:91:0f:47:42:64:22:5d:
    d4:84:7d:85:99
prime2:
    00:c1:e0:b5:ca:28:7a:46:2f:d3:46:ec:86:7c:20:
    c2:49:d6:20:5c:aa:4a:c4:5f:fd:88:d0:ba:f2:e3:
    33:9a:d4:29:dc:94:5b:3c:05:99:2e:7f:a6:3a:73:
    34:e1:2a:58:a9:c4:69:c1:cf:ed:5c:b1:a8:45:e0:
    e0:cc:c2:06:bb
exponent1:
    0f:ed:f7:0c:d0:72:a7:a7:4b:a5:8a:cc:5f:a9:dd:
    12:9c:03:8b:75:90:40:4a:ef:61:1c:3e:ef:85:f5:
    09:dd:da:ac:de:6d:ea:ab:92:41:73:0f:3a:98:b0:
    87:2a:92:63:70:ab:e3:d8:e0:f4:37:68:07:52:40:
    1e:fa:d8:21
exponent2:
    63:f8:fd:84:aa:ee:b2:36:83:19:b5:69:7b:a4:60:
    cb:36:31:25:d7:62:0a:74:fd:05:89:ac:7d:06:8f:
    5b:ad:3f:90:d0:a7:63:01:f8:05:34:29:81:46:5a:
    e4:28:b3:e3:86:b6:8a:0c:2f:f7:76:5c:b0:fb:ce:
    af:86:f5:75
coefficient:
    00:c0:30:ec:87:5f:7b:d2:c6:ab:b8:17:3a:aa:de:
    7c:6b:3e:24:5d:12:ca:d6:87:7d:df:b8:28:df:b1:
    b6:c6:46:0b:13:98:82:2b:82:8b:ea:1a:2f:cd:5a:
    17:e5:54:a3:17:d6:e6:0f:68:c1:76:73:2e:08:8f:
    18:66:ef:b6:cd
```

I'm trying to read the contents of this file and tokenize each components/blocks separately (like modulus, publicExponent, privateExponent, etc.) using the following code. However, When I'm trying to read from the file, seems like I'm not reading the whole content,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define KEY_BUFFER_SIZE 2560
unsigned char private_size[2070];

int main() {

    FILE * fp2 = fopen ("privateKey.txt", "r");
    int size_key=KEY_BUFFER_SIZE;
    if(fp2){
        fread(private_size,1,sizeof (private_size),fp2);
        //fgets(private_size,sizeof (private_size),fp2);
    }
    fclose(fp2);

    while(size_key>0){
        size_key=size_key-1;
    }

    printf("%s\n",private_size);

 return 0;
 }
```

**output:**

```
RSA Private-Key: (1024 bit, 2 primes)
modulus:
    00:a3:38:61:b8:4a:29:60:2c:2f:6c:df:3b:e1:9b:
    b9:13:96:8f:dc:7f:b4:5a:7c:6d:61:6e:f4:df:63:
    36:1b:7c:97:b9:f5:03:8e:40:7e:ca:48:00:5f:b6:
    a3:51:66:39:7b:d2:b6:f0:5e:5e:93:de:e0:ec:c6:
    ae:bb:c5:3d:50:be:ca:e1:02:d0:0b:e2:36:75:43:
    e0:64:81:25:92:a6:26:e3:55:d8:cf:fe:f5:44:4f:
    c5:d5:1d:8a:6e:d2:3e:61:50:72:95:26:a2:7f:8a:
    66:a6:57:da:58:13:c7:9a:d4:b7:cb:5d:c7:c7:5e:
    d4:94:e5:b8:cc:e2:c4:2c:c3
publicExponent: 65537 (0x10001)
privateExponent:
    21:19:4b:e7:bd:52:4a:a8:6b:2d:9e:cf:5b:de:e2:
    57:30:8f:17:dd:e5:ca:fb:b4:8a:af:9f:84:b5:6f:
    c1:7f:30:9d:8b:2c:1f:6a:c0:cb:70:72:72:f6:6c:
    84:13:40:d0:f5:58:17:c2:6b:57:7d:39:0b:8a:f6:
    e0:29:0d:57:c1:73:99:1a:e1:e7:bc:52:15:89:08:
    7e:d5:cb:dc:be:0b:af:32:4c:b1:f3:cc:ea:bc:95:
    1a:37:19:5c:de:94:be:ca:9b:57:fb:42:01:1c:42:
    db:d5:b2:d4:16:f7:f2:dd:7f:28:c4:bb:67:9d:21:
    ef:4b:d2:b8:78:cf:f6:61
prime1:
    00:d7:84:e9:f3:4a:2b:f9:c2:de:a4:ce:6c:5d:57:
    fa:bd:77:c3:83:55:cf:b0:42:c8:9d:e4:85:60:dd:
    c8:9a:e4:f8:52:80:ac:fa:cb:33:36:2f:cf:ad:8d:
    2a:7b:9e:6a:dc:6f:94:d9:91:0f:47:42:64:22:5d:
    d4:84:7d:85:99
prime2:
    00:c1:e0:b5:ca:28:7a:46:2f:d3:46:ec:86:7c:20:
    c2:49:d6:20:5c:aa:4a:c4:5f:fd:88:d0:ba:f2:e3:
    33:9a:d4:29:dc:94:5b:3c:05:99:2e:7f:a6:3a:73:
    34:e1:2a:58:a9:c4:69:c1:cf:ed:5c:b1:a8:45:e0:
    e0:cc:c2:06:bb
exponent1:
    0f:ed:f7:0c:d0:72:a7:a7:4b:a5:8a:cc:5f:a9:dd:
    12:9c:03:8b:75:90:40:4a:ef:61:1c:3e:ef:85:f5:
    09:dd:da:ac:de:6d:ea:ab:92:41:73:0f:3a:98:b0:
    87:2a:92:63:70:ab:e3:d8:e0:f4:37:68:07:52:40:
    1e:fa:d8:21
exponent2:
    63:f8:fd:84:aa:ee:b2:36:83:19:b5:69:7b:a4:60:
    cb:36:31:25:d7:62:0a:74:fd:05:89:ac:7d:06:8f:
    5b:ad:3f:90:d0:a7:63:01:f8:05:34:29:81:46:5a:
    e4:28:b3:e3:86:b6:8a:0c:2f:f7:76:5c:b0:fb:ce:
    af:86:f5:75
coefficient:
    00:c0:30:ec:87:5f:7b:d2:c6:ab:b8:17:3a:aa:de:
    7c:6b:3e:24:5d:12:ca:d6:87:7d:df:b8:28:df:b1:
    b6:c6:46:0b:13:98:82:2b:82:8b:ea:1a:2f:cd:5a:
    17:e5:54:a3:17:d6:e6:0f:68:c1:76:73:2e:0
```

I'm not sure from where the first two lines of the output are coming from.

**Update:**
**I have updated my code and output according to the suggestions and now I'm able to read the whole file correctly using the above code**

Comment: For one thing, you print the tokens from `strtok` in the wrong place. Print it once, as the first instruction in the `while` loop. So you print it temporally *after* the check for `NULL` pointer instead of before it. For another thing, if you begin with a text file, use text-type functions to read it (such as `fgets`) not binary-type `fread`.

Comment: Are you asking about the reading or about the parsing?

Comment: Note that you do not have a NUL-terminated string, on which to use string functions.

Comment: @einpoklum, I'm asking about reading.

Comment: @WeatherVane, I replace `fread` with `fgets`. But now it's not looping through. It's maybe due to the reason that I do not have a NUL-terminated string. However, using `fread` loop through the entire string. Is there any way to get the block as a token?

Comment: You use `fgets` like this: `while(fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, fp2) != NULL) { /* process the string */ }` The data in the text file has no NUL terminators, and `fread` does not supply them, but `fgets` does.

Comment: user45698746: So I would remove the rest of the program, and your bottom question about tokenization. You can ask another question later if you need to. Right now thr question is a bit confusing. Anyway, one-off reading of the whole file like @alinsoar suggests should work fine.

Comment: @einpoklum, ok. I will remove the second question, the associate code and ask a separate question

Comment: Please do not edit the original question, please respect the rules of StackOverflow.

Comment: @einpoklum Please do not edit my answer, the OP modified his/her original question.

Comment: @alinsoar: With respect - it is you who isn't respecting the rules. There is no reason to keep the original question if an edit clarifies or focuses it, or if it needs to be split up. And this is the case even if someone has already answered. You are perhaps confusing our customs with those of codereview.SX, where indeed you do not change your code after posting it. As for your own answer - you are certainly free to edit it back, my edit was only a suggestion.

Comment: @einpoklum  Ok, the problem was, my answer did not have complete meaning after s/he updated.  But it is indeed correct to update the question, but it is hard to follow a timeline logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(fp2)
        fread(private_size,1,sizeof (private_size),fp2);
fclose(fp2);
```

should be enough.

I think `RSA Private-Key: (1024 bit, 2 primes)` should not be included in the input file, as it is hard to parse it.

Other problem comes from the fact that you do not instrument the compiler to consider the correct signature for `strtok_r` by doing

```
 #include <string.h>
```

In the case you do not declare the correct signature, it uses the `K&R` calling convention, and this is wrong here, as automatic conversion from `char*` toward `int` and back is *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @user45698746 Ok, please do not edit the original question, otherwise you mislead the other users of SO.